# Required_if with more than one field in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have the following situation: I have a form and in it I have a field that I need to validate if two other fields are true.

For example, I have the holder_name field, I need this field to be mandatory if a radio type field called paymentMethod is equal to credit_car and if another radio called card is equal to n_card

I tried to do it like this:

```
'paymentMethod' => 'required|credit_card', 
'holder_name.*' => 'required_if:paymentMethod,credit_card', 

'card' => 'required|card', 
'holder_name.*' => 'required_if:card,n_card',
```

and so too

```
"holder_name" => 'required_if:paymentMethod,==,credit_card|required_if:card,==,n_card',
```

But I was not successful. Can anyone give me a light?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom validation like :

```
"holder_name" => 'required , function($request) {
                              return ( $request->paymentMethod == $request->credit_card
                              && $request->card == $request-> n_card) }',
```

Take a look at [**conditionally-adding-rules**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom rule for required if

```
 holder_name.*' => Rule::requiredIf(function () {
                                
        if(somecondition){
        
               return false;
        }
        
        
              return true;
      }),
```

This method must return true or false

For ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-if

```
Rule::requiredIf(function () {
                            if($this->paymentMethod==$this->credit_card && $this->card==n_card){
                            
                                return true;
                            }

                      return false;
                    }),
```

If you are not using FormRequest then

```
Rule::requiredIf(function ()use($request) {
                            if($request->paymentMethod==$request->credit_card && $request->card==n_card){
                            
                                return true;
                            }

                      return false;
                    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

the way it worked for me was:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
'holder_name' => Rule::requiredIf($data['paymentMethod'] == 'credit_card' 
 && $data['card'] == 'n_card')],$messages);
```

Tank's